# How to convert from % of FSR to LSB (DAC)?

Tags: dac

If a DAC has a gain error of ±0.1% of FSR and an offset error of ±1 mV.
Operating range 2.7-5.5 V with a reference voltage of 4.096 V.

How would I convert that ±0.1% of FSR to LSB? The datasheet doesn't give it in LSB units.

Is there an equation? The only one I know is:
$$ LSB = \frac{FSR}{2^n-1} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If \$p_\%\$ is the quantity in percent of \$FSR\$ and \$xLSB\$ is the correspondent representation in LSB:

$$ 1 LSB \rightarrow \frac{FSR}{2^n-1} $$
$$ x LSB \rightarrow \frac{p_\%}{100}\times FSR $$

$$  x LSB =  \frac{p_\%}{100} \times (2^n-1) $$

An example from SLAA013 - Understanding Data Converters from Texas Instruments:
*... offset  error,  gain  error,  integral  nonlinearity  and  differential nonlinearity. Each can be expressed in LSB units or sometimes as a percentage of the FSR. For example, an error of 1/2 LSB for an 8-bit converter corresponds to 0.2% FSR...*